# Facebook Hackbook example (android) not logging in

Tags: android, facebook

I have followed all the instructions from [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/) walk-through, and get all the way up and through installing the actual Facebook app.

When I build and run the code (on Virtual Device or actual android with USB cord), the main ui pops up with the message "You are logged out!" and the button to log in, but every time I click the button, I am shown a white screen with the blue Facebook title bar and a spinning progress bar, but then am dumped back to the main UI without being shown a dialog to log in or do anything.

If I click either "Update Status" or "App Requests" I am told that I am not logged in, but am given a place to enter my email/password. Once logged in through those, I can use both of these features, but none of the other ones. (The rest still all say I'm not logged in).

I am relatively confident that I have generated and used the correct Hash Key to register my app with facebook.

Additional problems: 
    App Requests: if the actual 'cancel' button is pressed, the toast still displays as "App request sent."

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated, as I'm very new to android development and Facebook integration in general, and I'd like to start making my own progress.

---

EDIT:
To follow up, I have had success for the past few weeks in using both Hackbook to log in and perform Graph API functions and my own personal use of similar code to log in to Facebook through the app I'm developing. Two out of the four days this work week it suddenly stopped working again, even though I haven't changed any of the SSO or Facebook portions of my code. Same exact characteristics: Facebook-esque title bar and spinning progress bar, then dumped back to the previous screen with no login dialog or session recognition. 
I am able to appropriately log in to Facebook via their own app for Android, but both the Hackbook and my own app either work or fail together.

Comment: Have you checked logcat for any error messages?

Comment: Logcat doesn't show any errors, unfortunately.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issues. Dont know what going on.

Comment: Any ideas with this one? Same problem with mine?